# referencing a namespace C# using XNA

Tags: c#, xna

I've been working in C# on my first major project, and have been trying to reference other C# class files and their namespaces, all of which are in the same solution.

The exact error I've been getting is: 'the type or namespace name 'theNamespace' could not be found' I've looked around and haven't found anything that fixes my issue. 
The following is an abridged version of my current code, which focuses on where the errors are detected.

```
using TileMap.MapRow.NET;
using tiles.tile.NET;

namespace Project
{
     public class Class1 {
     Tilemap.MapRow.TileMap myMap = new TileMap();
     }
     protected override void LoadContent() {
     tile.tilesettexture=Content.Load<Texture2D>("@textures");
     }
}
```

the classes that I'm trying to call are as follows:

```
namespace TileMap
{
     public class MapRow
    {
        public int TileMap ()
        {
            for (int y=0; y<MapHeight; y++)
            { MapRow thisRow=new MapRow();
                for (int x=0; x<MapWidth; x++){
                     thisRow.Columns.Add(new MapCell(0));
                }
                Row.Add(thisRow);
            }}
        public List<MapCell> Columns = new List<MapCell>();
        public List<MapRow> Rows = new List<MapRow>();
        public int MapWidth = 50;
        public int MapHeight = 50;        
        }
}
```

and

```
namespace tiles
{
    static class tile
    {
        static public Texture2D TileSetTexture;

        static public Rectangle GetSourceRectangle(int tileindex)
        {
             return new Rectangle(tileindex * 32, 0, 32, 32);
         }
    }
}
```

any suggestions would be wonderful.

Comment: Have you added their projects as references in your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `Tilemap.MapRow.TileMap myMap = new TileMap();` does not make sense. `TileMap` is not a type, but a method of the class `Tilemap.MapRow`. You cannot instantiate it. Furthermore, it should be `TileMap.MapRow` not `Tilemap.MapRow` (notice the capital M).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
using TileMap;
using tiles;
```

and when you want to access the methods

```
MapRow myMap = new  MapRow();
int i =  myMap.TileMap();
```

and For Static class

```
Rectangle r =  tile.GetSourceRectangle(1);
```